# View changes sizes when tab is changed

Tags: ios, swift, view, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tabBarController with 5 views . The problem is that when I change tabs the view size changes from what it was initially and it messes up my UI. On coming back to the tab, there is also a content offset. I have set the 
`self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false` but that does not help either. 
Here are the outputs to

```
print(self.view.frame)
```

> When App launches for the first time output is (0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 568.0)
>
> When tab is changed and I come back to the home view, the Output is (0.0, 64.0, 320.0, 455.0)

How can I fix this?

Comment: are you creating tabBarController manually ? like using creating multiple xibs or nibs and then using them in tabBarController?

Comment: Yes created it manually @AbdulRehmanWarraich

Comment: kindly share some code. That will help to understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is:

When you are running application at that time your view is not considering navigation bar height there for its origin y is 0.0 and when you are changing tab it is detecting navigation bar on screen so view is considering navigation bar above it and takes its origin 64.0 (which is 20.0 status bar and 44.0 navigation  bar).

To solve this:

You can set view controller property under top bar Yes/No as per requirement OR you can take one subview and set its frame according to main view frame as per your need in ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear.

Hope this might help you. :)